# Simple proxy reverse Apache-Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, apache-2.4

My intent is very simple, I would like to type example.com and be redirect to example.com:8080/myapp

example.com:8080/myapp is a java/tomcat app.

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example.com

    ProxyPass / example.com:8080/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse / example.com:8080/myapp/
    ProxyRequests Off
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(/.*) example.com:8080/myapp/$1 [P]

    <Proxy example.com:8080/myapp*>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    </VirtualHost>
```

And the result is when I type http://example.com it's redirected to example.com:8080/myapp/myapp

My file server.xml from Tomcat has the follow instruction:

```
      Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           proxyPort="80" proxyName="example.com"
```

What I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

1. The `rewriterule` should not be needed. What about deleting it?
2. Can you modify the virtual host to:

   ```
   <Location / >
           ProxyPass  http://localhost:8080/myapp
           ProxyPassReverse  http://localhost:8080/myapp
   </Location>
   ```

   (I removed a trailing slash)